# How to validate dynamic generated input box value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm creating multiple textbox dynamically, I want to do textbox validation like (textbox should not be empty) while form submission.

I'm not able to capture textbox id or name on form submit jquery function, can someone help how can I validate all dynamically created textboxes using JavaScript/jquery.

I'm using below code to generate multiple textboxes dynamically:

```
var input = $("<input/>", {
    type: "text",
    name: "productPrice",
    class: "form-control",
    id: obj.productName + "Id",
    value: obj.productPrice
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Check this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/kjdx9gfw/

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless the question is specifically about this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from Ranjeet Singh's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjdx9gfw/2/

```
$('#form_submit').find('input').each(function(i, input){
    var $input = $(input);
    $input.css('background-color', $input.val() ? 'green' : 'red');
});
```

Basically, it is iterating through every `input` inside the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what are you trying to do exactly but maybe if you put `<input required/>` you got the textbox should not be empty

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the jsfiddle link Which is working according your .
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sanjayarakeri/fqkh398h/